# Python --> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, string, int

HELP, my program is to say what year you are born and then tell you how old you are but I get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

If someone tells me why or me send the code well done I would appreciate it very much, thanks.

```
import  datetime
year = int(input("in what year were you born? ---> "))
yearac = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
print(year)
print(yearac)
difere = year - yearac
print("You have",(difere),"years")
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You specifically made `year` an integer and `yearac` a string.  You can't subtract those.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `int(input("in what year were you born? ---> "))`, what do you think the `int` part means? Why is it there? What would the result for `year` be otherwise? Now, think carefully about the next line, `yearac = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")`. What is the result for `yearac`? (Hint: what is the last word in the error message?) What should it be? (Hint: what is `year`? What do you want the `-` in `year - yearac` to do?) Therefore, how should you fix the `yearac` value? (Hint: the same way that you did for the `year` value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because yearac is a string. Try int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))

Answer (score 1):

`strftime` (as the name suggests) returns a `str`ing, and even though you can cast it to an integer using `int` like you're doing with the input, you should use the `year` attribute instead to get the year as an integer:

```
 yearac = datetime.date.today().year
```

Answer (score 0):

use yearac = datetime.date.today().year